# Ошибка Cannot check answer. Perhaps output format is wrong на Stepik

Tags: python, python-3.x

***Задача:***

Напишите программу, которая считывает с консоли числа (по одному в строке) до тех пор, пока сумма введённых чисел не будет равна 0 и сразу после этого выводит сумму квадратов всех считанных чисел.
Гарантируется, что в какой-то момент сумма введённых чисел окажется равной 0, после этого считывание продолжать не нужно.
В примере мы считываем числа 1, -3, 5, -6, -10, 13; в этот момент замечаем, что сумма этих чисел равна нулю и выводим сумму их квадратов, не обращая внимания на то, что остались ещё не прочитанные значения.

Sample Input:

1
-3
5
-6
-10
13
4
-8

Sample Output:
340

***Решение:***

```
b=int(input())
c=b**2
a=0
f=0
d=a+b
while b!=0 :
    a=int(input()) 
    d+=a
    s=a**2
    f+=s
    if d==0:
        print(c+f)
        break
```

***Проблема:***
В IDLE все работает,ошибок не было.Сайт не принимает решение из-за вот такой ошибки:

> Cannot check answer. Perhaps output format is wrong.

Не могу понять что не так,помогите пожалуйста.

Comment: А что именно за сайт? Возможно он так же печатает ваш output, что там?

Comment: @Viktorov Сайт Stepik.Шаг 2.6-Задачи по материалам недели.

Comment: Дайте ссылку на курс пож

Comment: @Viktorov https://stepik.org/lesson/3369/step/7?auth=login&unit=952

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ошибка `Cannot check answer. Perhaps output format is wrong.` обозначает, что ваша программа возвращает ответ в неприемлемом формате и проверочная система не может его распознать.
На примере текущей задачи, ожидаемый ответ - число(например `340`). Stepik ругается, что программа печатает не число или не печатает число(*ваш случай*).

Ваша программа успешно отработала на  наборе `1 -3 5 -6 -10 13 4 -8`. А  ошибка только на третьем тесте. Входной набор данных для третьего теста скрыт, однако по коду видно, что если первым числом ввести 0, то программа будет работать не правильно.

PS

Сознательно не написал рабочий вариант программы, т.к. это задача учебная и я и так почти весь ответ сказал.